# Getting Db4o blobs out of the Database without storing them to disk

Tags: java, blob, db4o

Is there a way to get a Db4o Blob out of the Database without storing it to disk?
I only found the method `void com.db4o.types.Blob.writeTo(File arg0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not =( There's no work around (except changing the db4o code). You have to work with files to use the db4o-blob type.

I agree that this is quite annoying.

As alternative you could use byte[]-arrays, which are more convenient to work with. However mind the db4o [file-size limitation](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/tuning/performance_hints/increasing_the_maximum_database_file_size.htm) when your using byte[]-arrays as blob.

Just some additional notes:

- You also need to poll for the state, which is also very annoying.
- Note that the blob IO runs outside the transaction.